# Event listener onclick does not work

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, event-listener

Onclick event does not work. Is it possible that element "td" can't have listener?

```
for (element in arr_big) {

   var cellOne = document.createElement("td");
   cellOne.innerHTML = '"<img src = "' + arr_big[element].src + '"/>"';

   cellOne.onclick = function showImage(cellOne) {
       console.log(cellOne.innerHTML);
   };
   row.appendChild(cellTwo);
   list_table_one.appendChild(row);
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It seems like you're not actually adding cellOne to the document. Is this all the code or did you remove parts of it?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? Is your element added to the document?

Comment: Can you post a demo code on jsFiddle?

Comment: You can click on it unless you attached it to DOM

Comment: @GudronSwiss: Mate, do you get any errors? Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0):

No, it can have a listener, but it has to be attached to the dom first

```
document.appendChild( cellOne );
```

before binding the event

Comment: I edited my post, i am appending a row element which has a childe cellOne. Now if i am doing row.onclick = function showImage(row) {     console.log(row);}; Nothing happens. No outputs, no errors..